# VSCode ignores my /android folder in react-native project

Tags: android, git, github, visual-studio-code

I have an ejected expo app which includes ios & android folder now.

`ios` folder is uploaded to GIT but my `/android` will be ignored and greyed out in vscode.

My `.gitignore`just includes the following lines:

```
node_modules/**/*
.expo/*
npm-debug.*
```

[image]

I cannot see any settings where I can reproduce this behavior. :(

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the issue. There was a wrong global gitignore configuration.

Steps to fix the issue.

1. `$ open ~/.gitconfig`
2. find path of .gitignore_global here:

[core] 
   excludesfile = /Users//.gitignore_global

2. `$ open /Users/<username>/.gitignore_global`